# How to turn a dictionary<string, int> elements into strings. c#

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, dictionary, int

I'm currently working on a game in which the top 5 highscores can be displayed on a highscores page.

Currently i have a dictionary of type [string, int] which will store the user's name and score respectively.However, i'm having trouble creating a method that will take all 5 dictionary elements in the format of {"name", 20} and assign each element to a string.

For example, dictionary element[0] contains the value {sam, 20}. I would like to assign this element to a string that would read "sam 20".

At the moment i have a method which will return the top5 highscores but my problem occurs when turning these values into strings from dictionary elements.

Any help would be appreciated and if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where is it failing for you?

Comment: An element is a `KeyValuePair<,>`, so you can get the key as a string and the value as an int... are you asking how to concatenate a string and an int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.Select()` and string interpolation to build out a projected string list:

```
var formattedStrings = dict
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                           .Select(x => $"{x.Key} {x.Value}").ToList();
```

Since `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, we can easily use LINQ to both order and project our key/value pairs before interpolating them into a new string.

This also allows for more flexible querying before projecting your list.

Comment: And assuming they probably what them ordered, throw in a `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)` before the `Select`

Comment: This is perfect, and yes @MattBurland i have already ordered the dictionary using this very method, Thanks all for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var answer= string.Join(",", map.Select(s => s.Key + " " +s.Value).ToArray());
```